# Call a slideDown() from other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got a working slideDown div in profile.php. When I click the Users Name the profile information dives slides down. Here is the structure,

profile.php - This works fine.

```
$('.showprofile').click(function() {
    $('#userprofile').slideDown(1000);
});
```

Where I am stuck is,

I want to have a link on users.php

```
<a href='profile.php#userprofile'>
```

when I click on the above link I should be taken to the profile.php page and then the userprofile div should slide down automatically.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use window.load() function for that. Then when the page loads the scrip is called.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.showprofile').click(function() {
        $('#userprofile').slideDown(1000);
    });
});
```

---

As per your comment: Try this::

```
var pathname = window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
if(pathname='users.php'){
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('.showprofile').click(function() {
            $('#userprofile').slideDown(1000);
        });
        });
    });
}else if{
    $('.showprofile').click(function() {
        $('#userprofile').slideDown(1000);
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you please expand your answer? i've got 2 pages pages users.php and profile.php

Comment: <a href='profile.php#userprofile'><a href='users.php#userprofile'>

Comment: I think you understood my question wrong. When I click a user link on users.php then the page should navigate to profile.php. Now in this page I have set the slideDown only on a CLICK event. But in this scenario i want the slide down to be automatic.

Comment: if you got an example like then please share it.

Comment: Perfect ! In addition to this logic I need to pass the user id from users.php in the url passed say profile.php?id=xxx can you help me out fetching the arguments passed in the url too ?

Comment: Your answer has several errors: 1. Extra `});` 2. `else if` missing condition 3. `pathname='users.php'` Invalid assignment

Answer (score 3):

Just add that code inside of `$(window).load()` of that page,

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(window).load(function(){
        $('#userprofile').slideDown(1000);
      });
    });
</script>
```

Note that, You should register `window.load()` inside `document.ready()`, Because There may be chances of the element with id `#userprofile` will not be available after the page loads.